# How can I remodel a data table to allow lookup via dynamically addable/removable factors?

Tags: sql, database-design

I'm having a brain freeze this morning and am hoping to bounce some ideas off the community. I have a lookup table in my database which I need to remodel - basic example of which is:

- Factor1
- Factor2
- Factor3
- Value

This has worked fine to this point but the business has now decided that the factors that go into looking up the value should be changeable by the user.

For instance, they may add a factor that has a list of possible values (i.e. another table), and that may be incorporated into the lookup, which with this style of table would require the addition of a column, i.e. Factor4.

My first thoughts are that we can't give users access to be able to create tables, columns, relationships and indexes in the database, that's just too much of an integrity risk, though this would probably be the most straightforward scenario.  Have the code that sets up the new factor column automatically create the table of values, generate the relationships, set up the index, modify the lookup stored proc etc. But that all seems like it's just not good practice at all.

Second thought is remodel so that the factors are specified just as values in a table, but this morning, I'm drawing a blank as to the approach I need to take so the lookup can be completed.  For a start, how do I complete a lookup when I have to look up which factors make up the decision on which value... it seems like I'm going to have to dynamically create a query, but that also doesn't seem like the right way to go.

Any ideas?

Let's say I have the following in my (original) table:

```
FactorValues
============
Factor1 | Factor2 | Factor3 | Value
-----------------------------------
 1         1         1         0.5
 1         1         2         1.0
 1         1         3         1.5
 1         2         1         2.0
 1         2         2         2.5
 1         2         3         3.0
```

I need to get value 3.0 (based on known factors), which is a cinch

```
Select Value 
From   FactorValues 
Where  Factor1 = 1 
And    Factor2 = 2 
And    Factor3 = 3
```

So now, let's say I've remodelled to the point that the end user could add a factor to the lookup, I still somehow need to be able to extract the values based on the semantics of:

```
Select Value
From   FactorValues
Where  FirstUserDefinedFactor = FirstSelectedValue
And    SecondUserDefinedFactor = SecondSelectedValue
And    NthUserDefinedFactor = NthSelectedValue
```

So the idea would be that my Value table would just become a key/value lookup, but I'm not sure how to model it so that I can do a where based on multiple rows instead of multiple columns...

Answer (score 1):

Some of what I think you want will be dependent on the interface you build for your users, but I think the interface will intuitively be constrained by the design, so here goes:

*data types listed are hypothetical of course, change as appropriate to your scenario*

Create one table of all the factors you want available to your users, or that you want them to be able to enter themselves:

```
Factor
-------
FactorID INT
Factor VARCHAR
```

Create another set of tables that will establish groups of factors, so your users can enter more than one as a single entry:

```
FactorGroup
-----------
FactorGroupID INT
FactorGroup VARCHAR

FactorGroupDetail
-----------------
FactorGroupDetailID INT
FactorGroupID INT
FactorID INT
```

Now, assuming your values are preset and you don't want them to change, you need a table for them as well:

```
Value
-----
ValueID INT
ValueName VARCHAR
Value DECIMAL
```

Otherwise, I would think you could just stick the `Value` field in the `FactorGroup` table.

Lastly, a table to match factor groups with the values:

```
FactorValue
-----------
FactorGroupID INT
ValueID INT
```

The query I think you'd need would probably be something like:

```
SELECT v.Value
FROM Value AS v
INNER JOIN FactorValue AS fv
    ON v.ValueID = fv.ValueID
INNER JOIN FactorGroup AS fg
    ON fv.FactorGroupID = fg.FactorGroupID
INNER JOIN FactorGroupDetail AS fgd
    ON fg.FactorGroupID = fgd.FactorGroupID
INNER JOIN Factor AS f
    ON fgd.FactorID = f.FactorID
WHERE f.FactorID IN (
    SELECT FactorID
    FROM Factor AS ftor
    WHERE ftor.Factor = @user_entered_factor1
        OR ftor.Factor = @user_entered_factor2
        OR ftor.Factor = @user_entered_factor3
)
```

Comment: This is what I've been thinking, but now I'm stuck at: How do I lookup the factor group id based on multiple factor detail values. The lookup isn't completed using a single factor, but all of them within the group. So I need to find the factor group ID based on Factor1 = a, Factor2 = b, FactorN = z etc. I understand the model I think I need to use, but I'm at a loss as to how to query that model now.

Comment: It would be an AND in this case... the lookup is inclusive of all selected factors.  I'll have a play with this and see if I can get it to do what I'm after.  Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting the gist of the problem right, you want to devise something that can capture the notion of:

```
f(X[i]) = y[i]
```

Where `f` is some sort of function, `X` is some n-tuple of factors, and y is the resultant value. (The `[i]` means subscript i.)

Assuming that `f` isn't going to change, then perhaps at minimum a two table approach may work.

```
Table A, Columns: Expression-Id, Factor-Index, Factor-Value

Table B, Columns: Expression-Id, Result-Value
```

`Expression-Id` indicates a particular relationship, i.e. the subscript i. `Result-Value` is the `y`. `Factor-Index` simply indicates which factor (1=Factor1, 2=Factor2, 3=Factor3, etc.) has the given `Factor-Value`.

An `Inner Join` on `Expression-Id` can knit the two tables together.

Hope this helps!

---

Or a one table approach, keeping Table A but dropping Table B. Use `Factor-Index`=0 to mean the y instead.